# Profile property not found in ASP.NET 4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-4.0, asp.net-profiles

I'm using ASP.NET 4 out-of-the-box forms authentication method. 
I want to add some custom properties to user's profiles so I've added the following code to my `web.config` file:

```
<profile enabled="true">

  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" 
         type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" 
         connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" 
         applicationName="/"/>
  </providers> 

  <properties>        
    <add name="DisplayName"/>
    <add name="PhoneNumber"/>
    <add name="FaxNumber"/>
    <add name="Email"/>
  </properties>

</profile>
```

But when I try to access any of these properties in an aspx file using something like:

```
TextBox.Text = Profile.DisplayName;
```

I get a red line under `DisplayName` and it's saying `ProjectName.Profile does not contain a definition for DisplayName`.

I've searched the net for several hours now and I'm quite clueless. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found it!

It looks as if one of the differences between "Web Applications" and "Web Sites" is the way it handles profiles. Web Sites have the ability to read the web.config file and dynamiclly create the profile class while web applications can't. As far as I understand one should create a custom profile class if using the Web Application project.

More information can be found here: http://www.codersbarn.com/post/2008/06/aspnet-web-site-versus-web-application-project.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the defaultProvider attribute on the profile node

```
<profile defaultProvider="AspNetSqlProfileProvider">
```

I assume you also have the Membership section defined for the provider to work and the connection string right ?

If not, you will probably need

```
<membership defaultProvider="SqlProvider" 
      userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="SqlProvider" 
          type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" 
          connectionStringName="SqlServices"
          applicationName="SampleApplication"
          enablePasswordRetrieval="true"
          enablePasswordReset="true"
          passwordFormat="Encrypted"
          requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" />
      </providers>
    </membership>

 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SqlServices" connectionString=
      "Data Source=localhost;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=aspnetdb;" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

The rest of the configuration looks ok.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion but it still doesn't work.
I have a working connection string and membership provider.